# how to remove the border around the tinymce editor

Tags: php, javascript, html, tinymce

Can somebody help me

Is it possible to remove the border from the tinymce **editor** itself?

I wonder if this can be done through css.

I've been searching through Google and all I came across with are removing borders from the tables.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hey, I think you must've solved your problem by now, and I'm facing the same issue, actually, I don't what elements should I edit in the CSS file, so it would be really helpful if you can share your CSS File.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may overwrite the styling for your tinymce UI html elements using the tinymce [editor_css](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs-3x/reference/configuration/Configuration3x@editor_css/) setting. Here youcan  define the path to a css file. The css in this file will overwrite the default tinymce css lettting you style the table element as desired.

Comment: glad to have been able to help

Comment: editor_css link is broken

Comment: link to editor_css documentation is fixed